# Identify the index corresponding to the smallest data in a set of arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, cursor

This is a trivial algorithmic question, I believe, but I don't seem to be able to find an efficient and elegant solution.

We have 3 arrays of int (Aa, Ab, Ac) and 3 cursors (Ca, Cb, Cc) that indicate an index in the corresponding array. I want to identify and increment the cursor pointing to the smallest value. If this cursor is already at the end of the array, I will exclude it and increment the cursor pointing to the second smallest value. If there is only 1 cursor that is not at the end of the array, we increment this one.

The only solutions I can come up are complicated and/or not optimal. For example, I always end up with a huge if...else...

Does anyone see a neat solution to this problem ?

I am programming in C++ but feel free to discuss it in pseudo-code or any language you like.

Thank you

Comment: What if Aa[Ca] == Ab[Cb] > Ac[Cc] and neither Ca nor Cb point to the end of their respective arrays? Do you increment Ca or Cb?

Comment: Isn't it a graph problem? Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path?

Comment: If the intention here is to have an output of a stream of numbers from the three arrays ordered lowest to highest you could simply put all three arrays into a larger vector and do a std::sort on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-java code:

```
int[] values = new int[3];
values[0] = aa[ca];
values[1] = ab[cb];
values[2] = ac[cc];
Arrays.sort(values);

boolean done = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 3 && !done; i++) {
    if (values[i] == aa[ca] && ca + 1 < aa.length) {
        ca++;
        done = true;
    }
    else if (values[i] == ab[cb] && cb + 1 < ab.length) {
        cb++;
        done = true;
    }
    else if (cc + 1 < ac.length) {
        cc++;
        done = true;
    }
}
if (!done) {
    System.out.println("cannot increment any index");
    stop = true;
}
```

Essentially, it does the following:

1. initialize an array `values` with `aa[ca]`, `ab[cb]` and `ac[cc]`
2. sort `values`
3. scan `values` and increment if possible (i.e. not already at the end of the array) the index of the corresponding value

I know, sorting is at best O(n lg n), but I'm only sorting an array of 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

what about this solution:

```
if (Ca != arraySize - 1) AND 
   ((Aa[Ca] == min(Aa[Ca], Ab[Cb], Ac[Cc]) OR 
    (Aa[Ca] == min(Aa[Ca], Ab[Cb]) And Cc == arraySize - 1) OR
    (Aa[Ca] == min(Aa[Ca], Ac[Cc]) And Cb == arraySize - 1) OR
    (Cc == arraySize - 1 And Cb == arraySize - 1))
{
    Ca++;
}
else if (Cb != arraySize - 1) AND 
        ((Ab[Cb] == min(Ab[Cb], Ac[Cc]) OR (Cc == arraySize - 1))
{
    Cb++;
}
else if (Cc != arraySize - 1) 
{
    Cc++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code: EDIT : tidied it up a bit

```
class CursoredArray
{
    int index;
    std::vector<int> array;

    int val()
    {
        return array[index];
    }

    bool moveNext()
    {
        bool ret = true;
        if( array.size() > index )
            ++index;
        else
            ret = false;
        return ret;
    }   
}    

std::vector<CursoredArray> arrays;
std::vector<int> order = { 0, 1, 2 };//have a default order to start with

if( arrays[0].val() > arrays[1].val() )
    std::swap( order[0], order [1] );

if( arrays[2].val() < arrays[order[1]].val() )//if the third is less than the largest of the others
{
    std::swap( order[1], order [2] );
    if( arrays[2].val() < arrays[order[0]].val() )//if the third is less than the smallest of the others
        std::swap( order[0], order [1] );
}  
//else third pos of order is already correct

bool end = true;

for( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{   
    if( arrays[order[i]].MoveNext() )
    {
        end = false;
        break;
    }
}

if( end )//have gone through all the arrays
```